# python regex not ending with some characters

Tags: python, regex

Hi hope the following code:

```
content ="'Yoda' :"
content = re.sub("\w\s*'\s*[^:]", "", content)
print content
```

print out: ***'Yoda' :***  but it printed ***'Yod:***
My intention is: if the string not ending with : then replace it with empty string, if ending with : then do nothing. but the above regex still replaced it. How can I modify the regex please. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the anchor `$` at the end of your regex,that specifies the end of string.

```
>>> content ="'Yoda' :"
>>> content = re.sub("\w\s*'\s*[^:]$", "", content)
>>> print (content)
'Yoda' :
```

But you can do this task without regex and just with `str.endswith()` :

```
content ="'Yoda' :"
if not content.endswith(':'):
    content=''
else:
    pass
```